# Как добавить некоторые данные (в самом начале) в xml файл при записи с DataSet?

Tags: c#, xml

Вот код:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 string fileName = @"izdelia.xml";
 dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;
 dt.WriteXml(fileName);
 MessageBox.Show("Данные сохранены в файл");
```

Запись получается такая:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
</NewDataSet>
```

А надо чтоб было так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt1.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>сталь</material>
    <number>1</number>
    <length>1</length>
    <width>2</width>
    <heigth>3</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дерево</material>
    <number>2</number>
    <length>2</length>
    <width>3</width>
    <heigth>4</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>пластмасса</material>
    <number>3</number>
    <length>4</length>
    <width>5</width>
    <heigth>6</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>ольха</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>100</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуб</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дубо</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
  <izdelia>
    <material>дуба</material>
    <number>10</number>
    <length>1000</length>
    <width>26</width>
    <heigth>89</heigth>
  </izdelia>
</NewDataSet>
```

Comment: dt.Rows.Add() перед dt.WriteXml - это ответ на вопрос как добавить спереди. Если вопрос как упорядочить - ответ другой. По заголовку непонятно чем первый xml отличается от второго.

Comment: @ nick_n_a Как не понятно то. Вот чем:                                                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt1.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>

Comment: Варианты:  1. Записать в память MemoryStream и выгрузить двумя кусками (шапка своя, данные записаные). 2 Выгружать в IStream написать обвёртку вставку.  3. Выгружать в XmlWriter - написать обвёртку-вставку.

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий код

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string fileName = @"izdelia.xml";
dt = (DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource;

var set = new XmlWriterSettings
{
    Indent = true
};
using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, set))
{
    w.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/xsl' href='xslt1.xsl'");
    w.WriteProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", "type='text/css' href='style.css'");
    dt.WriteXml(w, true);
}
MessageBox.Show("Данные сохранены в файл");
```

Comment: Ошибка в строке: doc.Load(fs);  Пишет что отсутствует корневой элемент

Comment: @SVD102, попробуйте прямо перед doc.Load(fs); дописать строку fs.Position = 0;

Comment: 2 записи добавились в конец файла а не в начало

Comment: @SVD102, попробуйте вместо AppendChild использовать PrependChild

Comment: Так вообще не записывает эти 2 строки. Вы сами вроде как не понимаете до конца что пишите. Я так понял.

Comment: @SVD102, странно что не записывает. У меня нет возможности протестировать это и отладить. Я написал код вслепую только исходя из описаний классов и методов. Попробуйте сами поэкспериментировать. Если не можете по какой то причине, то потерпите, я смогу это сделать через пару часов либо завтра.

Comment: Записывает, но в середину, так и не смог исправить.

Comment: Можете ответить, очень надо.

Comment: @SVD102, добрался до студии... )) А вас не смутило, что этот код не просто в середину пишет, а дублирует данные таблицы, к тому же убирает заголовок xml? :) Сейчас посмотрю как можно исправить

Comment: @SVD102 обновил ответ, проверил, у меня пашет )