# Записываю DataSet в xml файл, и получаю пустой файл, где ошибка?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string fileName = @"izdelia.xml";
dt = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Copy();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
System.IO.FileStream myFileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Create);
//System.Xml.XmlTextWriter myXmlWriter = new System.Xml.XmlTextWriter(myFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode);
System.Xml.XmlDataDocument  xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDataDocument(ds);
xmlDoc.DataSet.EnforceConstraints = false;
System.Xml.XmlDeclaration xmlDec = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes");
xmlDoc.PrependChild(xmlDec);
System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter;
xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(myFileStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlWriter);
```

Comment: А почему вы не закрываете (через using, разумеется) ваш поток, XmlWriter и всё остальное? Проблема может быть в этом.

Comment: @VladD Точно, но 1 строка получилась такая:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>. Как убрать  standalone="true"

Comment: А может лучше так:  dt.WriteXml(filename);

Comment: @nick_n_a Нет. так хуже

Comment: @SVD102: Это уже другая проблема, гляньте настройки XmlWriter'а.

Comment: @SVD102: может быть, это из-за EnforceConstraints?

Comment: Я в предыдущей вашей теме ответил. Там заодно и способ записи можете подсмотреть )

Comment: @iRumba Я вам писал в той теме, а вы не отвечали и до их пор нет ответа!

Comment: Вы под какую версию дотнета пишете? У вас используются устаревшие классы: `XmlDataDocument`, `XmlTextWriter` - если вы не ограничены версией 1.0, то лучше их не использовать.

Comment: @SVD102, как нет то? Обновите страницу блин ) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/528738/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B2-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81-dataset/528797?noredirect=1#comment659491_528797

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, проблема с незакрытыми `XmlWriter`'ом и `FileStream`'ом. Оберните их использование в `using`.